# 14.04 software centre problems after trying to download dropbox

Tags: dropbox

After trying to download Dropbox I get an error message in top bar of screen:
 "Unknown error ''(E:Malfomed line 56 in source list/etc/apt/sources.list(distparse))' This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies."

It suggested running Package Manager or apt-get in the terminal but that produced nothing very helpful. As a newbie to Ubuntu I'm rather lost!

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and enter:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Thanks for that: the response was 0 to upgrade, 0 to install, 0 to remove, 9 not to upgrade.

Comment: Do you still get the error message?